# What is the right way to create a bintray repository using API

Tags: bintray

I tried to create a bintray repository. But no matter what I specify as repository type it always create a `generic` repository. Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you please share the `create repository` JSON payload you are sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentations](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-CreateRepository) it states that you need to supply the **type** in the payload, as shown here: `"type": "maven"`.

The possible types are (currently): *maven*, *debian*, *conan*, *rpm*, *docker*, *npm*, *opkg*, *nuget*, *vagrant* and *generic* (**default**).

Check that you have at least this minimal payload:

```
{
  "name": "myMavenRepo",
  "type": "maven",
  "desc": "This repo is my greatest maven repo",
}
```

Comment: Oops, I was using http instead of https. :(